How to deploy a Vue Storefront 2 app on a self hosted linux server?
I'm struggling to understand how to deploy a Vue Storefront 2 app on my Ubuntu machine.
I've developed my app, inside the packages folder I have the three api-client, composables and theme folders. When I run yarn build from the root folder it creates the lib folders in composables and api-client and the .nuxt folder in the theme folder. Now the question: what should I upload on my linux server in order to perform nuxt start and see my application up and running? I'm not interested in how to configure NGINX, I'm capable of doing that. What I'm not understanding is what to pick after the build. Am I really obliged to upload the entire project on my server (it's several GBs)?

How would you load the project if it's not fully uploaded? Nginx is indeed the way to go.

I know that nginx is needed but that's not the point. If I want to deploy a traditional nuxt app I just upload the .nuxt folder, the package.json, I run yarn install and then yarn start. In this case it doesn't work this way. So what do I have to upload on the server?

Think about having a CI environment. It will take ages to upload the entire project on the remote server, there must be another way!

The .nuxt folder is for caching mostly. You could use project like Coolify or any other helpers to not have to deal with it yourself and handle the whole infrastructure. That way you can wire it to a CI and deploy it there with a simple git push. Might take 5/10min but this is usually the case for any serious medium-sized+ project, nothing weird or unusual. The question might be why is your project several GB? Also is it once bundled or before? Because you do not need to ship the bundle eveytime if building on the server itself, might even be faster because of the CPU.
